# Why is my computer out of battery when I wake it from hibernation?

Tags: laptop, battery, hibernate

I use hibernate, I don't know what happens, with other modes. Sometimes (not always) when I turn the computer on, it says, that battery is too low (like 4% or something). I use the computer mostly with the charger, it should be fully charged, when I turn it off.
The computer somehow turns itself on. I don't know why or how, but several times I have heard the "error noise", and it's warm in the morning.
I checked, taht the maintenance time is not set to night and not allowed to wake the computer, I checked, that the computer is not allowed to restart, when some error happens.
I am using windows 10

Comment: After asking the machine to hibernate, do you unplug it from the power?

Comment: yes, I do. I had hibernation issues in the past in that it wouldn't hibernate, but it does now

Comment: And you shut the lid before it finishes hibernating?

Comment: I hibernate by shutting the lid (it's set to hibernate when the lid closes)

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it would seem that the machine isn't fully entering hibernation, thus leaving the power active to the machine. Since you unplug the machine, the battery drains as it's still in use.

The causes for this could be :-

- A Windows Error popping up, preventing completion of the process
- An in the hiberfil.sys file (where windows stores all the memory information)
- Another timer or setting which sends the machine to sleep or standby (two states which are low power, but still require power)

To diagnose or resolve this, set the power options to do nothing with the lid closes, and then ensure there is a good timer on other power options such as sleep and standby. Set the machine to hibernate only from your action (start menu). Observe the hibernating process until the power switches off, then remove the power from the screen. If it hibernates properly, you know that it's the other timers causing the issue. If it doesn't you'll get an error message which you can act on, and further diagnose the issue.

One other cause of hibernation problems is available disk space on the root drive (usually C:). You need at LEAST the total amount of RAM, as available disk space. If you are close to the limit, then that may account for the unpredictability of hibernation.

Answer (score 0):

Could be some BIOS option, normally called something like `Charge USB devices even when laptop is powered off.`

I’ve seen it waste 10% overnight on a ThinkPad just trying to detect if something was plugged in USB. Could be that if you are leaving something plugged to the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Lenovo Thinkpad or Yoga, there are two options which can cause this: 1) fast startup is enabled, or 2) power off charging

Full details with screenshots are available at https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/yoga-series/yoga-3-pro-1370-laptop-lenovo/solutions/ht509457-battery-may-discharge-when-laptop-is-powered-off-or-in-a-sleep-state-thinkpad-ideapad